# next.js trouble with cookies

Tags: reactjs, cookies, next.js

I need to save my data from array to cookies, but I have some issues. :)
At the begining here bellow my code:

```
import { LineChartProps } from "./LineChart.props";
import { Input } from "../Input/Input";
import { Button } from "../Button/Button";
import cookie from "js-cookie";

import React, { useState, useEffect  } from "react";


export const LineChart = ({ }: LineChartProps): JSX.Element => {

    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
    const [citiesList, setCitiesList] = useState<string[]>(
        (cookie.get("citiesList")?.split(",")) || [
            "London",
            "Kyiv",
            "Los Angeles"
        ]
    );//array in state


    const onChange = ((event) => {
        setInputValue(event.target.value); 
    });

    const onClick = ((event) => {
        setCitiesList((currentArray) => [...currentArray, inputValue])
        console.log(citiesList)
    });


    useEffect(() => {
        cookie.set("citiesList", JSON.stringify(citiesList), { path: '' });
    }, [citiesList]);

    return (
        <div>
            <Button appearance="primary" onClick={onClick}>click me</Button>
            <Input type="text" name="search" onChange={onChange} />
            <div>
                <p>{inputValue}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};
```

To simplify it I'll also add here screenshot of my code:

[image]

As you see I have an array with cities. I want to save my array data to cookies, because I use next.js, but not a react.

I have button and input field:
[image]

So when I start my app, my array looks like this:

[image]

but for example if I reaload the page, I'll see this:

[image]

Then if I reload one more time, this:

[image]

So, what is better? Prevent cookies.set if all of elements are already in cookies, or there is other (better) solution for this?

And the second problem is: When I add some cities to my cookies Array, at the begining it looks like this:
[image]

But if I refresh the page twice, I'll see this:

[image]

Do you have any idea?

And if so, thanks in advance! Will be waiting for any solution:)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `JSON.parse` instead:

```
const [citiesList, setCitiesList] = useState<string[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const defaultCities = ["London","Kyiv","Los Angeles"]
  const cities = cookie.get("citiesList");
  if (!cities) {
    setCitiesList(defaultCities)
  } else {
    try {
      setCitiesList(JSON.parse(cities))
    } catch (err) {
      setCitiesList(defaultCities)
    }
  }
}, [])
```